# Click button to go to ListActivity on Android

Tags: android, button, android-intent, listactivity, extends

I have a button, here is the code:

```
Button bHotel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bHotel);
    bHotel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, HotelList.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

If i click that button, my intention it will go to:

```
public class HotelList extends ListActivity{
........    
        }
```

My question is why my application has stopped unexpectedly, but if i change the extends to Activity not ListActivity it run just fine.

In manifest i register the HotelList class as an Activity

```
<activity android:name=".HotelList" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: It could has to do with the layout... do you have a `ListView` whose id is `@android:id/list`?

Answer (score 1):

In case of ListActivity there is no need to `setContentView(R.layout.xml_file_name);`. I think you use in HotelList class above line as `setContentView(R.layout.xml_file_name);`. Remove line it will work.

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)
Screen Layout

ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in thecenter of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

Answer (score 0):

Did you use setContentView method in your second activity? If so remove it since your activity extends ListActivity, also how did you populate your list? I think there is a problem with the way you declared the id of the ListView, it has to be **"@android:id/list"** or else it won't work.

Comment: Please write "you" instead of "u". Chat-speak isn't welcome here.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it, will take care of that the next time:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your own layout, ListActivity expects a ListView inside the layout with id `"@android:id/list"`. Make sure that you have a ListView declared in your layout and that the id of that ListView is "@android:id/list"